# THREE.SpotLight onlyShadow replacement?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The onlyShadow property has now been removed from THREE.SpotLight. How can I use the THREE.SpotLight to only cast shadows in the latest builds? (Basically to produce the same effect)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the intensity to 0 while constructing the spot light.

Comment: I have tried this (var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0);) but now there are no shadows at all

Answer (score 0):

You can set Object Material's opacity to 0 in Properties.

[Material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material)

Eg:

```
var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 8, 3);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, cubeMaterial);
```

The cube effect of onlyShadow set as follows:

> [Set opacity and Adjust Light.shadow.bais](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBaYa.jpg)